# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword not working as expectedly

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. When succesful, `then` callback should be running. However, it is not. `whenComplete` callback is running as expected. There is no error, so `onError` is not running, as expected. It is a problem because I need the parameter in the `then`.

Why is it doing this?

I am using Flutter Web

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                      await auth
                          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: emailController.text,
                              password: passwordController.text)
                          .then((value) => () async {
                                print("user created");
                           
                                return value;
                              })
                          .whenComplete(() {
                        print("when callback");
                      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                        print("error: $error");
                        return Future.value();
                      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

```
FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

                      UserCredential uc =
                          await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: emailController.text,
                              password: passwordController.text)
                      .onError((error, stackTrace)  
                          {
                            // error callback
                          });
                      print(uc.user!.uid);
                      print("user created");
                      // do stuff with uc.user.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  // For registering a new user
 static Future<User?> registerUsingEmailPassword({
 required String name,
 required String email,
required String password,
 }) async {
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User? user;

try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await 
 `enter code here`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: email.trim(),
    password: password.trim(),
  );

  user = userCredential.user;
  await user!.updateDisplayName(name);
  await user.reload();
  user = auth.currentUser;
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test on it to make sure process - the theory - it go to whenComplete before go to then please - it is process.

Comment: I did, it just does not call the `then` callback. Even if I delete the `whenComplete` and `onError`

Comment: So if it work like your description please write it become 1 more method. 1 method return "then" - 1 method method1().whenComplete().

Comment: Hope it can work with you - if not - I need open my ide to see

Comment: also this is not an answer, should be a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).